# cake php: HTML links for certain id?

Tags: php, html, image, cakephp, echo

I'm new to CakePHP, I was wondering if there is a way to echo information from the database using a foreach loop but only have HTML links on images where the id is 1 & 7. What's the best way of achieving this?

```
<?php if ( isset($articles) ){ ?>
        <?php foreach($articles as $article):?>
        <?php echo ($this->Html->image($article['Post']['picture'], array('alt' =>    'storyimage', 'class' => 'smallimg'));?>
        <h3 class="caps"><?php echo $article['Post']['genre'];?></h3>
        <h2><?php echo $article['Post']['story'];?></h2>
        <div id="contentbox2">
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

This is how it looks in the veiw, my database in looks image data is stored like this:
suki-burberry-sq_500_500_90_s_c1.jpg
Would it be best to echo all the data individually without the foreach loop or could I write an if statement?

Comment: Your code already contains an example of an `if` statement. Use one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to get the 1 & 7 id you can do this, assuming that it is a predefined number. If it is dynamic or changeable you can do that in your controller.

```
<?php if ( isset($articles) ){ ?>

        <?php foreach($articles as $article):?>

        <?php if ($article['Post']['id']==1 || if ($article['Post']['id']==7) ): ?>

        <?php echo ($this->Html->image($article['Post']['picture'], array('alt' =>    'storyimage', 'class' => 'smallimg'));?>
        <h3 class="caps"><?php echo $article['Post']['genre'];?></h3>
        <h2><?php echo $article['Post']['story'];?></h2>
        <div id="contentbox2">
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to find from your Model only what you needed.

with the condition `$conditions=array('Post.id'=>array(1,7));`

Comment: If you want more detial, please paste your model & controller :D